# Why is Vuetify CSS applying outside of the Vue instance?

Tags: css, scope, vuejs2, components, vuetify.js

We are using Vuetify in a VueJS 2 app.

This Vue app is used inside another web application which doesn't use Vue.

However the CSS of Vuetify is leaking out of the Vue app. This causes the Vuetify CSS to apply styles to the web application and changes its styles, which is an undesired side effect.

How could we avoid the Vuetify CSS leaking out of Vue app?

Comment: Are you saying that when including `Vuetify` in your app, it breaks the styles of it?

Comment: Yes. The style of Vuetify breaks the style of my app.

Comment: Well, if you read the warning here https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start, below the **Existing Applications** header, you'll see that they don't guarantee to not break your styles.